# Finding length of a value from an input not working

Tags: java

So, the point of this project is to use the Luhn Algorithm on a 16 digit input. My code so far is as follows:

```
        boolean boo = false;
        while (!boo) {
            System.out.print("Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): ");
            String cardNumberSt = input.nextLine();
            int cardNumber = Integer.parseInt(cardNumberSt);
            int numLength = String.valueOf(cardNumberSt).length();

            if (numLength > 16 || numLength < 16) {
                System.out.println("ERROR! You MUST have exactly 16 digits");
                System.out.println();
            } else if (numLength == 16) {
                System.out.println("16 digits!");
            }
        }
```

The part of the code that breaks is the else-if statement, which results in an error at line 19, the value of the int cardNumber is not used. I'm a beginner programmer in Java, and have never came upon a problem like this. Idk if I need to use an array, use a nextInt(), or something else. Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: It's not an *error*, its a *warning*. It just means that after the value is assigned to `cardNumber`, you aren't using it anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Well, read the warning. It has a meaning. It says you never use the variable cardNumber. That could be the sign of a bug, or it could be that this variable is simply useless. It's up to you to analyze the situation: why do you declare and initialize a variable if you never use it?

Comment: Side note : your `while-loop` is infinite - when will the value of `boo` change to `true` so the loop can exit?

Comment: It will be used later in the project. I'll fix the infinite loop, but when I put 16 digits in the console I only get an error, not "16 digits!"

Comment: Print out the value of `numLength` before the if and see the value.

Comment: for 16 digits you must use `long` instead `int` otherwise `Integer.parseInt(cardNumberSt)` gives an exception

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `int cardNumber = Integer.parseInt(cardNumberSt);` line. You are not using `cardNumber` variable in your code, you only write it but it's never read.

Comment: damnit... that worked... whoops... I added it because I thought I could use it for later. I'll comment it out just in case